# const C Struct Array within Struct Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am attempting to create a const structure in C but can't seem to figure it out.

```
typedef struct sA{
 char* fname;
 char* lname;
} A;
```

To use as an Array:

```
A list[] = {{"david","smith"},{"john","smith"}};
```

However, if I have use a second struct:

```
typedef struct sB{
 A inList[]; 
} B;
```

I want to define a const structure as:

```
B newList[] = {
 {
   {"david","smith"}
 },
 {
   {"john","doe"}
   {"joe","doe"}
 }
};
```

`len(newList[0].inList)` is different from `len(newList[1].inList)`.  This can be built dynamically, but how would you build this into a const variable in C?

Comment: this post/code doesn't make any sense. string inside `single quote`? `unreferenced symbol`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the objects of a struct will always have same size. What you are trying do will result in different object of a struct having different sizes, which is not possible. So what you are trying to do is not correct

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, wanted to confirm my thoughts!